# Service inject into another service

Tags: angularjs

I got problem to inject a service to another one, however when I tested separately it seems work fine then.

My project structure is like this, `app.html` includes `app.js`, `service1.js`, `service2.js`, and they are `placed in order`.

Below is my code:

app.js

```
var aoApp = angular.module('aoApp', []);

aoApp.run(function (permissionService, userService) {
    userService.setPermissions("['admin']");
    permissionService.print();
});
```

service1.js

```
var app = angular.module('aoApp');

app.service('userService', function(){
    var user = {
        permissions: []
    };

    this.setPermissions = function(permissions){
        user.permissions = permissions;
    };

    this.getPermissions = function(){
        return user.permissions;
    };
    return this;
});
```

service2.js

```
    var app = angular.module('aoApp');

    app.service('permissionService', function(userService){

        var userGrantedPermissions = userService.getPermissions();

        //Here always print '[]' rather '['admin']'
        console.log(userGrantedPermissions);        

        this.print = function(){
            console.log(userGrantedPermissions);
        };
        return this;
    });
```

Problem is in service2.js (permissionService), parameter `userGrantedPermissions` is expected to be ['admin'], however its value keeps the default value '[]', I don't know if do something wrong here, but I tried to tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/14825/), it works! so what's wrong with my code now? why doesn't it work here?

Comment: I think in your actual implementation you are dealing with promises..

Comment: do console.log in set and check is it actually settings the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the execution of your code.

```
var app = angular.module('apps', []);

app.service('s1', function(){
    console.log('in s1 ctor');
    return this;
});

app.service('s2', function(s1){
    console.log('in s2 ctor');
    return this;
});

app.run(function(s1, s2){
    console.log('executing run');
});
```

This will print:

```
in s1 ctor
in s2 ctor
executing run
```

Since the ctors run before the `run` method.

Your Fiddle example doesn't run the code the same way you do in your original example.

The original example does this in the ctor:

```
 var userGrantedPermissions = userService.getPermissions();
```

Which is executed before the `run` method and therefore returns the init value `[]`.

Your fiddle executes a method and doesn't run anything in the ctor.

Check out this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/boht4f4t/).

Comment: ohh, I c I c, in my Fiddle I put the `read` into a function rather than construction scope, that's y I can get the value when I execute the `print` function, hmm